# Can ACRA be used in a library project?

Tags: android, init, illegalstateexception, acra

ACRA itself is crashing with a odd problem:

`IllegalStateException: Cannot access ErrorReporter before ACRA#init`

I have an app with ACRA 4.3.0 that works perfectly.  I changed the entire app to a library, so I can make minor variants. I created a new project that is entirely blank other than a manifest and links to this new library. For any one else attempting this, in AcraApplication.java you have to remove the "resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text" line and add a new line below Acra.init(this);

`ACRA.getConfig().setResToastText(R.string.crash_toast_text);`

The project builds fine and in debug I've confirmed ACRA.init(this); is run before the my main program code and before the error occurs.  In the main program, at the point where we set some custom data:

`ACRA.getErrorReporter().putCustomData("Orientation", "L");`

It causes the crash (or more accurately, ACRA itself causes the error) and no ACRA report is generated.

Any ideas what to try next or pointers where to look? It may be ACRA is incompatible with libraries, which if this is the case, I can pull it out an handle it differently, but sort of defeats the purpose of the library.

---

Solution: Instead of adding the line below `Acra.init(this);` add these three lines prior to the init line:

```
ACRAConfiguration config = ACRA.getNewDefaultConfig(this); 
config.setResToastText(R.string.crash_toast_text);
ACRA.setConfig(config);

ACRA.init(this);
```

Note this only works in v4.3.0 and later.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, it was caused by proguard obfuscation.

The solution is to add the below customizations to proguard.cfg file (taken from ACRA wiki page [here](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/Proguard)):

Note that the ACRA.init() should stay at the beginning:

```
@Override
  public void onCreate() {
    ACRA.init(this);
    ACRA.getErrorReporter().setReportSender(new MySender());

    super.onCreate();
  }
```

proguard.cfg:

```
#ACRA specifics
# we need line numbers in our stack traces otherwise they are pretty useless
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# ACRA needs "annotations" so add this... 
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# keep this class so that logging will show 'ACRA' and not a obfuscated name like 'a'.
# Note: if you are removing log messages elsewhere in this file then this isn't necessary
-keep class org.acra.ACRA {
    *;
}

# keep this around for some enums that ACRA needs
-keep class org.acra.ReportingInteractionMode {
    *;
}

-keepnames class org.acra.sender.HttpSender$** {
    *;
}

-keepnames class org.acra.ReportField {
    *;
}

# keep this otherwise it is removed by ProGuard
-keep public class org.acra.ErrorReporter
{
    public void addCustomData(java.lang.String,java.lang.String);
    public void putCustomData(java.lang.String,java.lang.String);
    public void removeCustomData(java.lang.String);
}

# keep this otherwise it is removed by ProGuard
-keep public class org.acra.ErrorReporter
{
    public void handleSilentException(java.lang.Throwable);
}
```

Comment: Hi, even with these lines in my proguard.cfg, I still get a "NoSuchFieldError :  SILENT" in my release. I can't figure it out

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have added in manifest file

```
<application
    android:name="com.test.MyApp"
```

and you have application class that do following

```
import org.acra.ACRA;
import org.acra.ReportField;
import org.acra.ReportingInteractionMode;
import org.acra.annotation.ReportsCrashes;

import android.app.Application;

@ReportsCrashes(formKey = "", mailTo = "your_email_address", customReportContent = {
            ReportField.APP_VERSION_CODE, ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME,
            ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION, ReportField.PHONE_MODEL,
            ReportField.CUSTOM_DATA, ReportField.STACK_TRACE, ReportField.LOGCAT }, mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST, resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text)
    public class MyApp extends Application
    {
        @Override
        public void onCreate()
        {
            super.onCreate();
            ACRA.init(this);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**In My case I was missing @ReportCrashes config... Hope this will work**

```
@ReportsCrashes(
    formUri = "uploadurl",
    reportType = HttpSender.Type.JSON,
    httpMethod = HttpSender.Method.POST,
    formUriBasicAuthLogin = "llenigingeneyederrownlys",
    formUriBasicAuthPassword = "1a35b13f9f54271d23a9aed988451182e5b97211",
    formKey = "", // This is required for backward compatibility but not used
    customReportContent = {
            ReportField.APP_VERSION_CODE,
            ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME,
            ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION,
            ReportField.PACKAGE_NAME,
            ReportField.REPORT_ID,
            ReportField.BUILD,
            ReportField.STACK_TRACE
    },
    mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
    resToastText =R.string.msg

)
```